# Magento 2 - How to change Product Name dynamically in configurable product view page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, php, configurable-product

How I can change my configurable product name and description dynamically when one option is selected, right now is change only the image, I need to do the same with the name and description.

**HTML structure:**

```
<div class="product media">
    <div class="product attribute description">
        <div class="value">
            <p>text description.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Did u manage to get it work ?
Thnx

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141080)

Comment: Solved this by simply using this . its really work for me. magento 2 configurable product module, you can enable product name , description etc https://codecanyon.net/item/magento-2-dynamic-configurable-product/22813380

Comment: Solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281021/how-to-change-product-name-dynamically-in-configurable-product-when-click-swatch/295051#295051

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try below custom module and modify according to your requirement.

**app/code/Anshu/SCdata/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_SCdata',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/SCdata/etc/module.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Anshu_SCdata" setup_version="1.0.0">
            <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_Swatches"/>
            </sequence>
        </module>
    </config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/SCdata/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
            <plugin name="anshu_configurable_product_configurable"
                    type="Anshu\SCdata\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Type\Configurable"
                    sortOrder="1"/>
        </type>
    </config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/SCdata/Block/ConfigurableProduct/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\SCdata\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Type;

use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\DecoderInterface;

class Configurable
{
    protected $jsonEncoder;
    protected $jsonDecoder;
    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
            EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
            DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder
    ) {
        $this->jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
    
    public function getProductById($id)
    {
        return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    }

    public function aroundGetJsonConfig(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $sname = [];
        $sdescription = [];
        
        $config = $proceed();
        $config = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($config);

        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $prod) {
            $id = $prod->getId();
            $product = $this->getProductById($id);
            $sname[$id] = $product->getName();
            $sdescription[$id] = $product->getDescription();
        }
        $config['sname'] = $sname;
        $config['sdescription'] = $sdescription;

        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }
}
```

**app/code/Anshu/SCdata/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer' : 'Anshu_SCdata/js/swatch-renderer',
            'magento-swatch.renderer' : 'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer',
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/Anshu/SCdata/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'jquery/ui',
  'magento-swatch.renderer'
], function($){
 
  $.widget('anshu.SwatchRenderer', $.mage.SwatchRenderer, { 
        
        /**
         * Event for swatch options
         *
         * @param {Object} $this
         * @param {Object} $widget
         * @private
         */
        _OnClick: function ($this, $widget) {
            var $parent = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass),
                $wrapper = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeOptionsWrapper),
                $label = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeSelectedOptionLabelClass),
                attributeId = $parent.attr('attribute-id'),
                $input = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput);

            if ($widget.inProductList) {
                $input = $widget.productForm.find(
                    '.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput + '[name="super_attribute[' + attributeId + ']"]'
                );
            }

            if ($this.hasClass('disabled')) {
                return;
            }

            if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
                $parent.removeAttr('option-selected').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $input.val('');
                $label.text('');
                $this.attr('aria-checked', false);
            } else {
                $parent.attr('option-selected', $this.attr('option-id')).find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $label.text($this.attr('option-label'));
                $input.val($this.attr('option-id'));
                $input.attr('data-attr-name', this._getAttributeCodeById(attributeId));
                $this.addClass('selected');
                $widget._toggleCheckedAttributes($this, $wrapper);
            }

            $widget._Rebuild();
            
            // Custom Code starts
            var iname = $widget.options.jsonConfig.sname[this.getProduct()];
            var idescription = $widget.options.jsonConfig.sdescription[this.getProduct()];
            
            if(idescription != ''){
                $('[data-role="content"]').find('.description .value').html(idescription);
            }
            if(iname != ''){
                $('[data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper"]').html(iname);
            }
            // Custom code ends

            if ($widget.element.parents($widget.options.selectorProduct)
                    .find(this.options.selectorProductPrice).is(':data(mage-priceBox)')
            ) {
                $widget._UpdatePrice();
            }

            $widget._loadMedia();
            $input.trigger('change');
        }
  
    });
 
  return $.anshu.SwatchRenderer;
});
```

---

**For Magento 2.4**

**For mixins you have to Add or Update app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer" : {
                "[VendorName]_[ModuleName]/js/swatch-renderer": true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**For mixins you have to Add or Update app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/jquery.parsequery'
], function ($, _) {
    'use strict';
    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer', widget, {

            /**
             * Event for swatch options
             *
             * @param {Object} $this
             * @param {Object} $widget
             * @private
             */
            _OnClick: function ($this, $widget) {

                $widget._super($this, $widget);

                $widget._UpdateDetailProduct();

            },

            /**
             * Event for select
             *
             * @param {Object} $this
             * @param {Object} $widget
             * @private
             */
            _OnChange: function ($this, $widget) {

                $widget._super($this, $widget);

                $widget._UpdateDetailProduct();

            },

            _UpdateDetailProduct: function () {
                var $widget = this,
                    index = '',
                    options = _.object(_.keys($widget.optionsMap), {}),
                    childProductName = this.options.jsonConfig.sname,
                    childProductDescription = this.options.jsonConfig.sdescription;

                $widget.element.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass + '[data-option-selected]').each(function () {
                    var attributeId = $(this).attr('data-attribute-id');
                    options[attributeId] = $(this).attr('data-option-selected');
                });

                /* CUSTOM CODE START */
                if (jQuery('[data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper"]').length && this.options.jsonConfig.sname) {
                    
                    console.log(this.getProduct());
                    if (this.getProduct()) {
                        var iname = this.options.jsonConfig.names[this.getProduct()][0].name
                        if (iname != '') {
                            jQuery('[data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper"]').html(iname);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        var productName = this.options.jsonConfig.productName
                        if (productName) {
                            jQuery('[data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper"]').html(productName);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (jQuery('.description > div.value').length && this.options.jsonConfig.sdescription) {
                    if (this.getProduct()) {
                        var description = this.options.jsonConfig.descriptions[this.getProduct()][0].description
                        if (description) {
                            jQuery('.description > div.value').html(description);
                        }
                    } else {
                        var productDescription = this.options.jsonConfig.productDescription
                        if (productDescription) {
                            jQuery('.description > div.value').html(productDescription);
                        }
                    }
                }
                /* CUSTOM CODE END */
            },
        });
        return $.mage.SwatchRenderer;
    }
});
```

---

** Output::**
[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your complete answer, I have only one issue the description is not work, I really don't know what is happened. can you check please?

Comment: I forgot to tell you,  in my custom theme I move the description here: <move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.media" before="product.info.media.image"/>
 maybe this can be the issue?

Comment: Change the code $('[data-role="content"]').find('.description .value').html(idescription); according to your placement of the element. Rest of the code will be the same.

Comment: I already do this but still not working

Comment: you have any idea what is wrong with this module? why is not work description?

Comment: As you have mentioned that you have changed the location of the description, that's why my code is not working for you. Change code $('[data-role="content"]').find('.description .value').html(idescription) according to your description location on the page.

Comment: please take a look I update my post and I add the html structure there, can you tell me how will be the correct line of code? Thanks

Comment: It is hard to figure out the issue by just looking at the html, but try $('[data-role="content"]').find('.product .description .value').html(idescription)

Comment: Or provide full html of the page

Comment: is not work, I add a image to see the html structure

Comment: Check if you can find [data-role="content"] in your page source.

Comment: Try $('#maincontent .product .description .value').html(idescription)

Comment: is perfect now, thank you very much, I really appreciate your efforts

Comment: Thanks for u code..Its working ..and also How can i change the additional Information data?

Comment: The solution is nice, but i have a concern does it's works dynamically when cache is enabled?

Comment: First i try this for magento 2.2.4 but it didn't work. I thought it could be version issue because this question is for 2.1 so then i tried it for 2.1.6 but it doesn't work for this too. @AnshuMishra do i need something else to make it work. any guess??

Comment: @AwaisKhan I have checked it with default magento installation and it worked for me. May be it is not working for you because you have any modification (html modifications) on the catalog page.

Comment: how to change dynamically for the custom attribute in magento2

Comment: @AnshuMishra - great solution. Can you tell me how do i change the product details when the configurable options are displayed in dropdown instead of swatches

Answer (score 4):

**Try following module:**

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php
> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Swatches"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="[VendorName]-[ModuleName]-product-block" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\Product\View\Type\ConfigurablePlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="[VendorName]-[ModuleName]-product-model" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\Product\Type\ConfigurablePlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> 4. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Plugin/Product/Type/ConfigurablePlugin.php

```
<?php 
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\Product\Type;

class ConfigurablePlugin
{
    public function afterGetUsedProductCollection(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $subject, $result)
    {
        $result->addAttributeToSelect('description');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

> 5. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Plugin/Product/View/Type/ConfigurablePlugin.php

```
<?php 

namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\Product\View\Type;

class ConfigurablePlugin
{
    protected $jsonEncoder;
    protected $jsonDecoder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Json\DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
    ){
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
    }

    public function afterGetJsonConfig(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject, $result)
    {
        $result = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($result);
        $currentProduct = $subject->getProduct();
        if ($currentProduct->getDescription()) {
            $result['productDescription'] = $currentProduct->getDescription();
        }

        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
            $result['descriptions'][$product->getId()][] =
                [
                    'description' => $product->getData('description'),
                ];
        }

        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($result);
    }
}
```

> 6. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer':'[VendorName]_[ModuleName]/js/swatch-renderer'
        }
    }
};
```

> 7. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

```
_OnClick: function ($this, $widget, eventName) {
    var $parent = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass),
        $wrapper = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeOptionsWrapper),
        $label = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeSelectedOptionLabelClass),
        attributeId = $parent.attr('attribute-id'),
        $input = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput);

    if ($widget.inProductList) {
        $input = $widget.productForm.find(
            '.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput + '[name="super_attribute[' + attributeId + ']"]'
        );
    }

    if ($this.hasClass('disabled')) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        $parent.removeAttr('option-selected').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $input.val('');
        $label.text('');
        $this.attr('aria-checked', false);
    } else {
        $parent.attr('option-selected', $this.attr('option-id')).find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $label.text($this.attr('option-label'));
        $input.val($this.attr('option-id'));
        $input.attr('data-attr-name', this._getAttributeCodeById(attributeId));
        $this.addClass('selected');
        $widget._toggleCheckedAttributes($this, $wrapper);

        /* CUSTOM CODE START */
        if (jQuery('.description > div.value').length && this.options.jsonConfig.descriptions) {
          if (this.getProduct()) {
            var description = this.options.jsonConfig.descriptions[this.getProduct()][0].description
            if(description) {
              jQuery('.description > div.value').html(description);
            }
          } else {
            var productDescription = this.options.jsonConfig.productDescription
            if(productDescription) {
              jQuery('.description > div.value').html(productDescription);
            }
          }
        }
        /* CUSTOM CODE END */
    }

    $widget._Rebuild();

    if ($widget.element.parents($widget.options.selectorProduct)
            .find(this.options.selectorProductPrice).is(':data(mage-priceBox)')
    ) {
        $widget._UpdatePrice();
    }

    $widget._loadMedia(eventName);
    $input.trigger('change');
},
```

**Note:** Copy original JS file(vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js) and paste on the above path and update above function(_OnClick) OR you can customize JS code as per your requirement. Here, you can also use minix to override JS function.

Comment: Hi thank you, but I think your code is not complete, I have errors

Comment: how to change the custom attribute for this

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, when choosing options, the *images* and the *price* will change. **But not  product name and description.**

More information about which elements on the page change when options are selected can be found here: `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()`.

In order to display the **product name** and **description** of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing **product name** and **description** for each simple product.

Switching **product name** and **description** when selecting an option can be implemented in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements) (`Visual Swatch`, `Text Swatch`, `Dropdown`).

---

I made `VCT Product Info Switcher` module on Magento Marketplace that solves this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an observer and event product before save and set your dynamically created description based in certain conditions