# Help to change configurable product description, sku dynamically?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

[How to change product name dynamically in configurable product when click swatches Magento 2.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281021/how-to-change-product-name-dynamically-in-configurable-product-when-click-swatch)

I followed the provided code in above link with help of a programmer by mistake I deleted etc folder  I managed to get env.php and. rest of the file from backup  which I had  before  adding  the above code but my website was not working
then I deleted 'custom_layout_update_file' now website working but I can't see configurable product any help
would appreciate

---

[image]

Please see the attached error coming  in the console  but can't see configurable product only parent product We can see.

Comment: I add a couple of configurable  products but it's just showing me parent product only  no child product and when I tried to add parent product in cart it's giving me the error you need to choose the option for your item.Simple product is wroking fine in my website i can easily add into cart any help would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

> Module Method Working For me in Magento 2.1 / 2.2 /2.3 ::
> The below Code is to change Name & Description both.
> For Magento 2.4 add mixin

---

**1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName_ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

**2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName_ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

**3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="[VendorName_ModuleName]-product-block" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\Product\View\Type\ConfigurablePlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="[VendorName_ModuleName]-product-model" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\Product\Type\ConfigurablePlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**4. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Plugin/Product/Type/ConfigurablePlugin.php**

```
<?php 
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\Product\Type;

    class ConfigurablePlugin
    {
        public function afterGetUsedProductCollection(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $subject, $result)
        {
            $result->addAttributeToSelect('name');
            $result->addAttributeToSelect('description');
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

**5. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Plugin/Product/View/Type/ConfigurablePlugin.php**

```
<?php 

namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\Product\View\Type;

class ConfigurablePlugin
{
    protected $jsonEncoder;
    protected $jsonDecoder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Json\DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
    ){
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
    }

    public function afterGetJsonConfig(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject, $result)
    {
        $result = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($result);
        $currentProduct = $subject->getProduct();
        
        if ($currentProduct->getName()) {
            $result['productName'] = $currentProduct->getName();
        }
        if ($currentProduct->getDescription()) {
            $result['productDescription'] = $currentProduct->getDescription();
        }
        if ($currentProduct->getSku()) {
            $result['productSku'] = $currentProduct->getSku();
        }
        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
            $result['names'][$product->getId()][] =
                [
                    'name' => $product->getData('name'),
                ];
            $result['descriptions'][$product->getId()][] =
                [
                    'description' => $product->getData('description'),
                ];
            $result['skus'][$product->getId()][] =
                [
                    'sku' => $product->getData('sku'),
                ];
        }
        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($result);
    }
}
```

**6. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer':'[VendorName]_[ModuleName]/js/swatch-renderer'
        }
    }
};
```

**7. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js**

> Copy original JS
> file(vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js
> & Replace _OnClick function with below code (Line No Approx: 712)

```
_OnClick: function ($this, $widget, eventName) {
            var $parent = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass),
                $wrapper = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeOptionsWrapper),
                $label = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeSelectedOptionLabelClass),
                attributeId = $parent.attr('attribute-id'),
                $input = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput);

            if ($widget.inProductList) {
                $input = $widget.productForm.find(
                    '.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput + '[name="super_attribute[' + attributeId + ']"]'
                );
            }

            if ($this.hasClass('disabled')) {
                return;
            }

            if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
                $parent.removeAttr('option-selected').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $input.val('');
                $label.text('');
                $this.attr('aria-checked', false);
            } else {
                $parent.attr('option-selected', $this.attr('option-id')).find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $label.text($this.attr('option-label'));
                $input.val($this.attr('option-id'));
                $input.attr('data-attr-name', this._getAttributeCodeById(attributeId));
                $this.addClass('selected');
                $widget._toggleCheckedAttributes($this, $wrapper);

                /* CUSTOM CODE START */
                if (jQuery('[data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper"]').length && this.options.jsonConfig.names) {
                    if (this.getProduct()) {
                        var iname = this.options.jsonConfig.names[this.getProduct()][0].name
                        if (iname != '') {
                            jQuery('[data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper"]').html(iname);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        var productName = this.options.jsonConfig.productName
                        if (productName) {
                            jQuery('[data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper"]').html(productName);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (jQuery('.description > div.value').length && this.options.jsonConfig.descriptions) {
                    if (this.getProduct()) {
                        var description = this.options.jsonConfig.descriptions[this.getProduct()][0].description
                        if (description) {
                            jQuery('.description > div.value').html(description);
                        }
                    } else {
                        var productDescription = this.options.jsonConfig.productDescription
                        if (productDescription) {
                            jQuery('.description > div.value').html(productDescription);
                        }
                    }
                }
                /* CUSTOM CODE END */

                $widget._Rebuild();

                if ($widget.element.parents($widget.options.selectorProduct)
                    .find(this.options.selectorProductPrice).is(':data(mage-priceBox)')
                ) {
                    $widget._UpdatePrice();
                }

                $widget._loadMedia(eventName);
                $input.trigger('change');
            }
        },
```

---

**For Magento 2.4**

**For mixins you have to Add or Update app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer" : {
                "[VendorName]_[ModuleName]/js/swatch-renderer": true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**For mixins you have to Add or Update app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/jquery.parsequery'
], function ($, _) {
    'use strict';
    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer', widget, {

            /**
             * Event for swatch options
             *
             * @param {Object} $this
             * @param {Object} $widget
             * @private
             */
            _OnClick: function ($this, $widget) {

                $widget._super($this, $widget);

                $widget._UpdateDetailProduct();

            },

            /**
             * Event for select
             *
             * @param {Object} $this
             * @param {Object} $widget
             * @private
             */
            _OnChange: function ($this, $widget) {

                $widget._super($this, $widget);

                $widget._UpdateDetailProduct();

            },

            _UpdateDetailProduct: function () {
                var $widget = this,
                    index = '',
                    options = _.object(_.keys($widget.optionsMap), {}),
                    childProductName = this.options.jsonConfig.names,
                    childProductDescription = this.options.jsonConfig.descriptions;
                    childProductSku = this.options.jsonConfig.skus;

                $widget.element.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass + '[data-option-selected]').each(function () {
                    var attributeId = $(this).attr('data-attribute-id');
                    options[attributeId] = $(this).attr('data-option-selected');
                });

                /* CUSTOM CODE START */
                if (jQuery('[data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper"]').length && this.options.jsonConfig.names) {
                    
                    if (this.getProduct()) {
                        var iname = this.options.jsonConfig.names[this.getProduct()][0].name
                        if (iname != '') {
                            jQuery('[data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper"]').html(iname);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        var productName = this.options.jsonConfig.productName
                        if (productName) {
                            jQuery('[data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper"]').html(productName);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (jQuery('.description > div.value').length && this.options.jsonConfig.descriptions) {
                    if (this.getProduct()) {
                        var description = this.options.jsonConfig.descriptions[this.getProduct()][0].description
                        if (description) {
                            jQuery('.description > div.value').html(description);
                        }
                    } else {
                        var productDescription = this.options.jsonConfig.productDescription
                        if (productDescription) {
                            jQuery('.description > div.value').html(productDescription);
                        }
                    }
                }
                var simpleSku = this.options.jsonConfig.skus[this.getProduct()][0].sku;

                if(simpleSku != '') {
                    $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html(simpleSku);
                }
                /* CUSTOM CODE END */
            },
        });
        return $.mage.SwatchRenderer;
    }
});
```

---

** Output::**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For shops, which are using a Hyvä Theme, our module might be an option:

https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/customgento-module-child-product-data.html

This updates the following attributes quick and easy:

- Product Name
- SKU
- Short Description
- Description
- “More Information” Block
- Related Products (performantly via AJAX)
- Upsell Products (performantly via AJAX)

You only need to enter the fitting identifiers of your Hyvä theme in the system configuration, and the module will do the rest.