# Ajax tabs for configurable product with description of child products

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, ajax, tabs

I need to create custom tab in configurable product that will check is there a description in child product that is selected now and load description of child product. So for example in configurable product i select color: Red, after this, it should check, does this child product have description, if yes, load custom tab with description. Any suggestions even extension would be nice, thank you.

Comment: follow this logic https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281021/how-to-change-product-name-dynamically-in-configurable-product-when-click-swatch

Comment: @Msquare Thank you, i will try to do this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added custom tab and used this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/295051/55392 to show description and name of child products

Answer (score 0):

For shops, which are using a Hyvä Theme, our module might be an option:

https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/customgento-module-child-product-data.html

This updates not only the description, but also the following attributes quick and easy:

- Product Name
- SKU
- Short Description
- “More Information” Block
- Related Products (performantly via AJAX)
- Upsell Products (performantly via AJAX)

You only need to enter the fitting identifiers of your Hyvä theme in the system configuration, and the module will do the rest.

Comment: Please don't duplicate the same answer across multiple questions, especially if you are linking to your own product. This may get removed as spam. If two questions have the same answer, then the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance, sorry, did not know that. Thought, that it all cases, our module would help, this is why I added the comment. But will make sure in the future, that this does not happen anymore. Thanks for the advise.