# Change product page details for configurable products

Tags: magento2, javascript, configurable-product

I have these configurable poducts with a single option wich changes just an attribute and maybe the price, but of course the tabs like details, reviews and another custom tab I made does not change whenone of the option. I select
What I want to accomplish is that my custom tab, the details tab and any other tab that I may like changes when changing the selected option. I think it's doable since in the backend each virtual product has its own description and itìs own attributes just like the configurable base one.
I think I may have to create a module with some javascirpt inside.

I hope I explained it well. Thanks in advance to who can help me

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/211200/1968

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to install your module:did enable, upgrade, di:compile: c:f but it does not work. I use magento 2.4. Does not work even with default Luma theme

Comment: This is just a sample code, you can take reference of it and create your own module.