# How to change product name dynamically in configurable product when click swatches Magento 2.4

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.4, configurable-swatches

[image]

How to Change the Configurable products name dynamically when i click configurable swatches, currently price change when click swatches .I need to change name too. please suggest better way! Thank You,

Comment: I would like to suggest a module: https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-simple-details-on-configurable-product-extension.html?BSS=2fb795a41461f9664f41efb0c07e9461

Comment: @HoangHieu: buying a module is not a solution. An actual extension code like https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281021/ would be perfect. :)

Comment: check this out => https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211133/magento-2-how-to-change-product-name-dynamically-in-configurable-product-view

Comment: So you can contact with me for build the extension with some cost.

Comment: Just upload a picture and requirement you can do you job without any resource??. HAHA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Magento 2.4**, you can change the product name dynamically by clicking on the configurable product swatch using JavaScript and jQuery.

Here are the steps to do it:

- First, create a JavaScript file in your Magento theme, for example, **configurable-swatch.js**.
- In the **configurable-swatch.js** file, add the following code to listen to the swatch click event:

  require(['jquery'], function($) {

  ```
   $(document).on('click', '.swatch-option', function() {

       var selectedOptions = $('.swatch-option.selected');
       var productName = $('.product-info-main .product-name').text();
       var selectedAttributes = [];

       selectedOptions.each(function() {
           var attributeId = $(this).closest('.swatch-attribute').attr('attribute-id');
           var optionId = $(this).attr('option-id');
           var attributeCode = $(this).closest('.swatch-attribute').attr('attribute-code');
           selectedAttributes[attributeCode] = optionId;
       });

       var newProductName = productName.replace(/\[[^\]]+\]/g, '').trim();
       for (var attributeCode in selectedAttributes) {
           var attributeValue = selectedAttributes[attributeCode];
           newProductName += ' [' + attributeValue + ']';
       }

       $('.product-info-main .product-name').text(newProductName);
   });
  ```

  });

Add the following link to your Magento theme's **Catalog_product_view.xml** layout file to include the **configurable-swatch.js** file:

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="configurable-swatch.js">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string">
                <![CDATA[
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/configurable-swatch.js"></script>
                ]]>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Using these steps, the product name will change dynamically when you click on the **configurable product swatch in Magento 2.4**.

Please note that this code may need to be modified based on your specific theme and requirements.

Comment: Do your module also work for custom attributes like Manufacturer or SKU? Or is it just the name? How to extend this for other attributes? :)

Comment: For sku and other filed you need to do customisation on Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js file.

let me know if you need demo code

Comment: Actually i guess mixins are just not loading at the moment. I'll create a new question for this topic. :)