Single product with a dropdown to related products
I would love to have something like this on a Magento 2.4.7 website:
Product Link
It shows a single product, with a dropdown 'Sizes', which gives the possibility to change to another single product (connected to related products?)
I tried to realize that with the bundle product, but unfortunately the description and the attributes are not changing to the individual single product.
Any idea how to do that, or does somebody know an extension for that?
Thanks
Bernard

Please review this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211133/magento-2-how-to-change-product-name-dynamically-in-configurable-product-view
Please let me know if its help

You can create a configurable product to have different size option on product detail page and follow the solution suggested by @GrazittiDev to achieve the feature of updating product details based on option selection.
